# Mock Lambda callback in Jest? (Cannot read property body of undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a lambda function but can't figure out how to mock the lambda `callback` so it stops code execution. The `callback` I mock up is being called, which in the case of a lambda would immediately return the response. In my unit tests though, it continues executing code and I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

I'm relatively new to Jest so not sure how to proceed.

`example.js` (lambda code)

```
// dependencies
const got = require('got');

// lambda handler
const example = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // message placeholder
  let message;

  // set request options
  const gotOptions = {
    json: {
      process: event.process
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  };

  // http response data
  const res = await got.post('https://some.url/api/process', gotOptions).catch((error) => {
    message = 'error calling process';

    // log and return the error
    console.log(message, error);
    callback(message);
  });

  // res.body is causing the error in the test since
  // this code still executes after callbacks triggered
  message = `Process ${event.process} is: ${res.body.active}`;


  callback(null, message);
};


// export example
exports.example = example;
```

`example.test.js` (unit test code)

```
// get the lib we want to test
const example = require('./example');

// setup mocks
jest.mock('got');

// mock our lambda callback
const callback = jest.fn();


// import the modules we want to mock
const got = require('got');


// set default event
let event = {
  process: 1
};

// set default context
const context = {};


// run before each test
beforeEach(() => {
  // set default got.post response
  got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
    body: {
      active: true
    }
  }));
});

// test artifact api
describe('[example]', () => {
  ...other tests that pass...

  test('error calling process api', async () => {
    let error = 'error calling process';

    // set got mock response for this test to error
    got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(error));

    // function we want to test w/ mock data
    await example.example(event, context, callback);

    // test our callback function to see if it matches our desired expectedResponse
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: If you change `got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(error))` in your test to `got.mockRejectedValue(error)`, does that do the trick?

Comment: It does not...the test fails with the following message which indicates the `catch` statement isn't being evaluated:
`Expected: "error calling process", Received: null, "Process 1 is: true"`

Answer (score 2):

1-add folder `__mocks__` in root project

2-add file `got.js` in `__mocks__` folder

3-add code to `got.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    post: (url, options) => {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            res({ body: { active: 'test' } })
        })
    }
}
```

4- in test file:

```
let example = require('./example');

let callback_arg1 = ''
let callback_arg2 = ''
let event = {
    process: 1
};
let context = {};
let callback = (arg1, arg2) => {
    callback_arg1 = arg1
    callback_arg2 = arg2
};


describe('example', () => {
    test('error calling process api', async () => {
        await example.example(event, context, callback);
        expect(callback_arg1).toBe(null)
        expect(callback_arg2).toBe('Process 1 is: test')
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the implementation of the `callback` function. In order to stop executing the code after error handling, you need to `throw new Error()`, and use `await expect(example.example(event, context, callback)).rejects.toThrow(error);` to catch the error to avoid test failure. In this way, we can simulate the behavior of aws lambda

E.g.

`example.js`:

```js
const got = require('got');

const example = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let message;

  const gotOptions = {
    json: {
      process: event.process,
    },
    responseType: 'json',
  };

  const res = await got.post('https://some.url/api/process', gotOptions).catch((error) => {
    callback(error);
  });

  console.log('process');
  message = `Process ${event.process} is: ${res.body.active}`;

  callback(null, message);
};

exports.example = example;
```

`example.test.js`:

```js
const example = require('./example');
const got = require('got');

jest.mock('got');
const callback = jest.fn().mockImplementation((errorMsg) => {
  if (errorMsg) throw new Error(errorMsg);
});
const event = { process: 1 };
const context = {};

describe('[example]', () => {
  test('error calling process api', async () => {
    let error = 'error calling process';
    got.post.mockRejectedValueOnce(error);
    await expect(example.example(event, context, callback)).rejects.toThrow(error);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });

  test('should success', async () => {
    got.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      body: { active: true },
    });
    await example.example(event, context, callback);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, 'Process 1 is: true');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66567679/example.test.js
  [example]
    ✓ error calling process api (5 ms)
    ✓ should success (10 ms)

  console.log
    process

      at examples/66567679/example.js:17:11

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 example.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.966 s, estimated 4 s
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two issues here

---

### Issue 1

Mixing `async` and `non-async`

A lambda function can either be `async` or `non-async`.

An `async` handler uses an `async` function that can either return or throw.  If a `Promise` is returned the lambda function will wait for the `Promise` to resolve or reject and return the result.

A `non-async` function uses a callback as the third argument and returns the result passed to the callback.

In this case the function is `async` but is also using a callback.  It should use either an `async` function **or** a callback function but not both.

---

### Issue 2

> The `callback` I mock up is being called, which in the case of a lambda would immediately return the response.

By default a lambda function does **not** immediately return the response when the callback is called.

If you use a [non-async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync), note that "execution continues until the event loop is empty or the function times out. **The response isn't sent to the invoker until all event loop tasks are finished.**"

(Note that you could set [`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) to `false` to get the lambda function to return right away, but this isn't a real solution since the state of the process will be frozen and will restart at that exact state the next time it is invoked so the error would just happen on the next invocation.)

So best practice is to ensure that a `non-async` lambda function is always able to run to completion since the value passed to the callback isn't actually passed back until the event loop is empty.

In the example above it might **look** like execution stops after the `callback` is invoked, but that is only because it looks like AWS does not report info on exceptions thrown after the `callback` is called with an error.

Here is a simple non-async handler to demonstrate:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('starting');  // logged
  callback('this error gets reported');  // callback called with an error
  console.log('still running');  // logged
  throw new Error('this error is not reported');  // not reported
  console.log('ending');  // not logged
};
```

---

### Solution

In this case I would just remove the `callback` argument and go with a purely `async` function.

Something like this:

```
const got = require('./got');

const example = async (event, context) => {
  const gotOptions = {
    json: {
      process: event.process
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  };

  return got.post('https://some.url/api/process', gotOptions)
  .then(res => `Process ${event.process} is: ${res.body.active}`)
  .catch((error) => {
    // log, format the returned error, etc.
    // (or just remove the catch to return the error as-is)
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(error);
  });
};

exports.example = example;
```

Then you can test the returned `Promise` directly like this:

```
const example = require('./example');

jest.mock('./got');

const got = require('./got');

// set default event
let event = {
  process: 1
};

// set default context
const context = {};

// run before each test
beforeEach(() => {
  // set default got.post response
  got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
    body: {
      active: true
    }
  }));
});

// test artifact api
describe('[example]', () => {
  test('error calling process api', async () => {
    let error = 'error calling process';

    // set got mock response for this test to error
    got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(error));

    // function we want to test w/ mock data
    await expect(example.example(event, context)).rejects.toThrow(error);  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jest supports testing code that uses callbacks. Your test can accept a `done` parameter.

See the jest documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous).

Applying that pattern to your test it could look like the following:

```
describe('[example]', () => {
  test('error calling process api', done => {
    const error = 'error calling process';

    got.post.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(error));

    await example.example(event, context, callbackError => {
      // used try...catch pattern from jest docs
      try { 
        expect(callbackError).toEqual(error);
      } catch (e) {
        done(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

*Notes*

1. The test is no longer `async` and accepts a `done` parameter.
2. The expectation needs to move into the callback.
3. The test will fail with a timeout if `done()` is not called.
4. The expectation needs a try/catch around it. I took this from [the documentation linked above](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous). It's a consequence of the `expect().toEqual...` in the callback. If the `expect` fails, `done` will not be called and the test will timeout, and then you'll get the timeout error rather than the more useful error from the `expect`.

This will get you going without having to switch it all over to use Promises.

---

Once you've played with that test and the code a bit you may run into a control flow bug in your main handler code.

[image: problem with calling the callback in the catch]

After calling `callback(error)` in the catch, the non-error path in the code is left hanging and fails. Failing because the result is undefined after the catch.

Jest/node will report this as an unresolved promise error and warn you that:

> In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My advice would be that if you're going to `await` the api call, then instead of using `.catch`, put a `try...catch` around it.

E.g.

```
try {
  const res = await got.post('https://some.url/api/process', gotOptions);
  message = `Process ${event.process} is: ${res.body.active}`;
  callback(null, message);
} catch (error) {
  message = 'error calling process';
  console.log(message, error);
  callback(message);
}
```

Or alternatively get rid of the `await` and use it like a promise.

E.g.

```
got.post('https://some.url/api/process', gotOptions)
  .then(res => {
    message = `Process ${event.process} is: ${res.body.active}`;
    callback(null, message);
  }).catch((error) => {
    message = 'error calling process';
    console.log(message, error);
    callback(message);
  });
```